# Turn off bluetooth on bedtime

Tags: bluetooth, google-pixel

Is there a native way to turn the bluetooth off every day between certain hours?

I now use ITTT, but couldn't find a native way.

Comment: As a Pixel 3a user, I don't think AOSP/Pixel's stock ROM provides this feature natively. I believe automation apps are still needed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.omarbs.bluesched&hl=en_US&gl=US) that seems to do what you need. It's description:

> Bluetooth Scheduler offers you the posibility to turn On and turn Off bluetooth module in different moments of the day, and/or through the week with day independent configurations, making you to save battery charge.
>
> There is 2 different modes (1 active each time):
>
> Simple mode: Lets you make schedules independent of the day, that should apply everyday.
>
> Weekly mode: Lets you easily configure schedules for each day of the week.

I didn't find a way to do it without an app (a native way). However, if you didn't like this app and you are a developer, [you can check the functionalities available](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/setup) and build yourself your app for that.